# Batch script to check if rdp connection is down, then reconnect

Tags: batch-file, command-line, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to create a batch script that outputs all of my current rdp connections. I am connected to multiple machines from my desktop, but lose connection to them every so often. Eventually, I'd like to schedule this task to run regularly and notify me so that I can go in a reconnect. For reference, I am using a non-admin account.

**Update:**

With the query posted below (found in another stackoverflow post), I am able to get a list of all connections listening in on port 3389. In a limited use environment, these should only be RDP connections.

```
netstat -n -a | findstr 3389 >"C:\Users\Public\log.txt"
```

Edit 1: Reworded question.

Edit 2: Found temporary solution.

Original question:

> The goal is to to schedule a task that checks a PC every XX minutes to
>   see if it is connected to some VM's via Remote Desktop Connection. If
>   it isn't connected to the right VM, then attempt to reconnect.  I
>   understand that I will need to schedule a batch file to run every XX
>   minutes, then have the batch file check the connections (the hard
>   part). I have looked around and I cannot find a clear answer as to
>   whether this is even possible.

Comment: This feels too broad of a question. What techniques are you thinking about using? Have you made any attempt at trying to solve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am having the most difficulty trying to figure out how look at all of my current rdp connections. I've edited my question to focus on that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

While not a batch solution, powershell is available for Most Windows Machines

**Powershell**

```
Using PowerShell 
=======================
import-module remotedesktopservices
Get-RDUserSession
```

**Results**

```
CollectionName DomainName Username HostServer UnifiedSessionId
============== ========== ======== ========== ================
Session Coll.. LocalHost  joe      d103joe    14
```

Comment: This requires administrator privileges, which unfortunately I cannot get in my environment.

Comment: ? RDP Session Queries ¿ On any remote system - will required an elevated permission request in order to poll the machine for an active state.  (Or am I missing something).   In general, what your asking to do is a default administrator access request.  Sounds kinda like your attempting to bypass security features built in to the systems to prevent you from doing what you are doing without said access.

Comment: The intent was just to get a list machines connected via RDP, nothing fishy! I seemed to have found workaround solution that queries for connections on port 3389 (the port RDP listens on). I am then able to compare these IP's against a list of my VM's IP's. I have updated my post with this temporary solution.